# How do I cut a picture in an aspect ratio while retaining a rectangle inside?

Tags: c#, math

My goal is to crop an image while keeping the aspect ratio 16:9 without losing parts of the original image by putting the original image in the center depending on current ratio.

My crop-size is `breiteNeu` for width of the image to be cropped and `hoeheNeu` for height of the image to be cropped. `xNeu` is the x-coordinate of the image to be cropped and `yNeu` is the y-coordinate of the image to be cropped.

This is my code

```
if (breiteNeu > hoeheNeu)
{
    if (breiteNeu / hoeheNeu > 1.777)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        float hj = 0.5625f * breiteNeu;
        yNeu -= (int)((hj - hoeheNeu) / 2);
        hoeheNeu = (int)hj;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        float bj = 1.777f * hoeheNeu;
        xNeu -= (int)((bj - breiteNeu) / 2);
        breiteNeu = (int)bj;
    }
}
else
{
    if (breiteNeu / hoeheNeu > 0.5625)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        float hj = 1.777f * breiteNeu;
        yNeu -= (int)((hj - hoeheNeu) / 2);
        hoeheNeu = (int)hj;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("4");
        float bj = 0.5625f * hoeheNeu;
        xNeu -= (int)((bj - breiteNeu) / 2);
        breiteNeu = (int)bj;
    }
}
```

1 to 3 ( `Console.WriteLine("1")` to `Console.WriteLine("3")` ) seem to work, but 4 always crops out parts of the image by reducing the width to keep the aspect ratio.

How do I need to change especially 4 to keep the aspect ratio yet contain the whole `breiteNeu` and `hoeheNeu`(the original ones before `hoeheNeu = hj` resp. `breiteNeu = bj` were assigned) area?

Comment: Don't use int when you have decimal numbers. Use decimal or float. That might even be enough to fix it.

Comment: @Sami I updated it. Still the same issue. Is the math correct?

Comment: You're still casting it to `int` here: `xNeu -= (int)((bj - breiteNeu) / 2);`. This will round it to the nearest full integer, and that might cause issues.

Comment: @Sami Those are pixel coordinates, they have to be `int`.

Comment: Ah, my bad.. Sorry, but I don't have the time to check the math right now. I assumed that the variable type would be the cause. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/346946/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, division between integers always results in an integer.  If both breiteNeu and hoeheNeu are integers, that may be causing the unexpected results.

Cast one of them to float to compare them properly to the float in your if statements.

if (breiteNeu / (float)hoeheNeu > 1.777)

and

if (breiteNeu / (float)hoeheNeu > 0.5625)

The math looks correct.